# Hybrid Search SharePoint 2013-2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, office-365, 2016, crawled-property

I have configured Hybrid Search in my SharePoint Onprem. I can also see some results in my O365, however I am wondering about the "Cralwed Properties".

My question is : Can I see "Cralwed Properties" which is there in Onprem on O365 ?.

Comment: Are you missing specific properties from on-prem in your O365 schema? I AM TOO! I've opened a ticket w/ Microsoft, they are still researching the issue. Let me know and I'll see if I can pull you in as additional reference for them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, All of your Property Management is not handled in SharePoint Online. Go to your SharePoint Online Admin Portal and choose the Search service. The Search Schema is where you will find the Managed and Crawled properties.

Comment: Hello Matthew, thank you for the reply. I actually can see Managed & Crawled Properties in online. But I they are different then what are there in SharePoint on-prem.

Comment: What do you mean by "different"? The on-prem properties will only be used by the on-prem query processor. If you set up a Remote Result Source to SPO from your on-prem SSA it will only use the MPs from SPO.